# Wordpress landing page works all other dont

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, server, hosting, migrate

I moved my live wordpress site from one hosting to another.

I changed values in my wp-config.php to point to new settings.

Entire DB is imported correctly and all files are placed correctly through FTP.

The problem is that only landing page is working fine. But all other internal links don't.

Please suggest.

> 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: update your permalink from wp-admin

Comment: Not able to access wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a issue of permalink . Go to dashboard and set permalink Plain and check your site . If it works then change the permalink according to your wish .

Hope this help you